# retrieve value from a hashie:mash which is inside another array

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to extract a value from the results returned from elasticsearch.
The result set returned is an Array and the objects inside the array are Hashie:Mash.

The resultset looks like this:

```
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[8.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[744.0] sampler_label=["globalnav"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="globalnav,1,744,200,8,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:12.472Z" @type="jm_type" _id="5ACJI7NqRvCK_THBiRszrQ">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[8.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[801.0] sampler_label=["globalnav"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="globalnav,1,801,200,8,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:12.489Z" @type="jm_type" _id="Mzpz30H3Qf6wLxx_IAO8uQ">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[8.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[10.0] sampler_label=["homepage"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="homepage,1,10,200,8,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:28.115Z" @type="jm_type" _id="vN8t39UmQwy9PxhRGKU5uQ">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[8.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[9.0] sampler_label=["homepage"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="homepage,1,9,200,8,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:28.196Z" @type="jm_type" _id="mMkV4sqwTEqU6OiY5-q3JA">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[10.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[747.0] sampler_label=["globalnav"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="globalnav,1,747,200,10,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:12.475Z" @type="jm_type" _id="LVZaHrExS7Cy8l9ndCBGIA">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[17.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[25.0] sampler_label=["random_content"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="random_content,1,25,200,17,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:28.185Z" @type="jm_type" _id="cLaYGsA_T9e2F70NbvoSqQ">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[800.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[808.0] sampler_label=["random_content"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="random_content,1,808,200,800,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:12.465Z" @type="jm_type" _id="OFbQcHyATDS2l-IWxltIug">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[15.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[20.0] sampler_label=["homepage"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="homepage,1,20,200,15,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:12.467Z" @type="jm_type" _id="gdz3yDkTSyqgn-2S5yirEg">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[393.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[400.0] sampler_label=["random_content"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="random_content,1,400,200,393,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:12.491Z" @type="jm_type" _id="5XGEVQzFS_S_OTLpD1KPfQ">
#<Hashie::Mash @fields=#<Hashie::Mash latency=[16.0] response_code=[200.0] response_time=[22.0] sampler_label=["random_content"] success=[1] my_id=["specnn1"]> @message="random_content,1,22,200,16,specnn1,\r" @source="file:///fqdn/ffw_spectrum.log" @source_host="xplda04.ieee.org" @source_path="/full/path/ffw_spectrum.log" @tags=["jm_type"] @timestamp="2013-02-04T20:47:12.504Z" @type="jm_type" _id="wi14pyNHRWaH6AK7874KiA">
```

I'm able to extract the response_time by looping through the array then looping through the hasie and looping through the array and then get to the value inside the hashie mash.

Is there an easy or effecient way to extract the `response_time` value using ruby?

Comment: Please provide a simple reproduce code, which objects you have and what exactly needs to be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Is `array.map(&:response_time)` doing what you want to achieve?